# Does maven-android-plugin supports multiple source folders?

Tags: android, maven, jenkins, directory

On my current Android Project we have some generated java code which we would like to build tru a CI(Jenkins) chain. This code should be place in some extra folder like:

```
src/main/java
src/main/some-generated-code
```

The Code will not generated using maven, its already in the repository. Is there support doing this with Android-Maven-Plugin ?

Any best practices for this ?

Thanks a lot,
Kitesurfer

Comment: I would create an own maven module, generate the sources there, build/deploy that module and use it as a dependency in your module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is to have the generated code stand on its own as a separate project that is deployed to a repository manager and declared as a dependency to the current project.

If that is not an option and the source code has to be in the location you reference you can try [the build-helper-maven-plugin to add more source folders](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html).